# Chaining Customizations with Autofixture

Tags: c#, autofixture

I know that `Autofixture` stops building object when it finds `ISpecimenBuilder` which can satisfy the request. So when I apply several consequent customizations, all but the last one get ignored. How do I combine the customizations instead? In other words, how do I modify this snippet:

```
fixture.Customize<SomeClass>(ob => ob.With(x => x.Id, 123)); // this customization is ignored
fixture.Customize<SomeClass>(ob => ob.With(x => x.Rev, 4341)); // only this one takes place
```

To be equivalent with this snippet:

```
fixture.Customize<SomeClass>(ob => ob
    .With(x => x.Id, 123)
    .With(x => x.Rev, 4341)); // both customization are applied
```

Comment: The short answer is that you **can't do this** out of the box with AutoFixture, and that it's by design. At one time, many years ago, I actually had a prototype that behaved like you'd like it to behave, instead of overwriting the previous customization, but after having tried it out for some time, I came to the conclusion that it was too confusing, and could lead to some *hard-to-understand* behaviours when things became more complicated. In the many years I've used AutoFixture, I've never had the need for doing this either, so I'm curious about the use case.

Comment: @MarkSeemann The use case is to apply a fluent-like interface. So that instead of something like fixture.SetupWithEmailAndCache() I could have fixture.WithEmail().WithCache(). Both enabling emails and enabling cache requires setting up certain properties on the configuration object as well as some other actions. But those properties nor actions do not intersect for email and cache so it makes no sense to put such setup into a single function.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. If you *commonly* need to address independent concerns in the same test code, what does that tell you about your System Under Test?

Comment: @MarkSeemann I don't see anything wrong with that - how else can you test a unit which is dependent on other units which are independent of each other? What is wrong with my example is that even though I claim my Email and Cache independent, they do have something in common - and that's the configuration object. This breaks Single Responsibility principle and leads to the issues with the testing. Another example - I have a customization which is common for the whole test suite; only in one test case I want to slightly change the setup, but to do that I would need to copy whole customization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```
public class CustomFixture : Fixture
{
    public CustomFixture ()
    {
        this.Inject(this);
    }

    private readonly List<object> _transformations = new List<object>();

    public void DelayedCustomize<T>(Func<ICustomizationComposer<T>, ISpecimenBuilder> composerTransformation)
    {
        this._transformations.Add(composerTransformation);
    }

    public void ApplyCustomize<T>()
    {
        this.Customize<T>(ob =>
        {
            return this._transformations.OfType<Func<ICustomizationComposer<T>, ISpecimenBuilder>>()
                .Aggregate(ob, (current, transformation) => (ICustomizationComposer<T>)transformation(current));
        });
    }

}
```

And the usage:

```
var fixture = new CustomFixture();

fixture.DelayedCustomize<SomeClass>(ob => ob.With(x => x.Id, 123)); 
fixture.DelayedCustomize<SomeClass>(ob => ob.With(x => x.Rev, 4341)); 
fixture.ApplyCustomize<SomeClass>();

var obj = fixture.Create<SomeClass>();
// obj.Id == 123
// obj.Rev == 4341
```

Not ideal because of the need of `ApplyCustomize`.